# How to verify a post-receive hook request actually came from github?

Tags: authentication, github, webhooks

[Github offers a way](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/) to let a URL know when a project has been updated using webhooks.

**How do I verify that a post sent to my server's post-receive hook actually came from github?**

Should I check the IP address of the sender or can I send an auth check somewhere? I want to make sure someone doesn't try to spoof a request pretending to be from github.

One option is to setup the hook through [PubSubHubbub](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#PubSubHubbub) and use the `hub.secret` option to create a SHA1 HMAC signature of the post body. However, that would require my server setting up the request rather than waiting for users to setup the post-receive callback to my site when they want to. I would rather just ask users to paste the URL I give them into the post url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to check Github's post-request IP : *207.97.227.253, 50.57.128.197, 108.171.174.178*

Comment: So simple I didn't even consider it. The data is not super important, I just want to stop simple spam submissions.

Comment: According to Github, the actual addresses are 207.97.227.253, 50.57.128.197, 108.171.174.178.

Comment: This sounds fragile.  If github ever changes those IP addresses, you'll have to update your list.  Perhaps you can do a reverse DNS lookup and ensure that the resulting domain name ends with "github.com".

Comment: @Joshua, can you please provide the source for that IP address information? I'm having trouble finding any information on github.com. Thanks!

Comment: I've seen those IPs too. Go to the Admin/Settings part of a repo, click Service Hooks, then click WebHook URLs. You'll see a message on the right: "The Public IP addresses for these hooks are: 207.97.227.253, 50.57.128.197, 108.171.174.178."

Comment: Don't use the above addresses, go get the current ones (a CIDR Range) as described in the comment by @RichDougherty

Comment: Don't look up IPs. Github has specific recommendations on verifying requests... see @Rowan's answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can ping [GitHub's Meta API](http://developer.github.com/v3/meta/) to get an array of IP addresses (in [CIDR](http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr) notation) that the incoming service hooks will originate from and cross check them against the request's IP :

https://api.github.com/meta

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [GitHub's docs on the subject](https://help.github.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-does-github-use-that-i-should-whitelist#service-hook-ip-addresses): they suggest using HTTPS and basic authentication.

Specifically, set up your Payload URL in this format:

https://yourUser:yourPass@yoursite.net/path

If you have a number of users, you'd give each a different username & password. Assuming they keep that password private, you can then trust that an authenticating request really does come from GitHub and from that account.

See also: https://github.com/blog/237-basic-auth-post-receives

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @mnml's answer, the second step could be to just call up the [API and verify](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) that the information given matches the last known commit for the project. It's the same process that OpenID uses to verify the data passed is valid.

So, first I could defeat dumb reply attacks, by just checking the IP. Next I could ask github if the information I received is correct.

```
GET /repos/:user/:repo/commits/:sha
```

Comment: Yep I also use the json data to trigger capistrano and deploy depending on the branch of the commit

Comment: **This is not safe** – everybody can add commits to your repo by creating pull requests. See here: https://api.github.com/repos/github/gitignore/git/commits/85be394529d93cb7f29cd758599e7d103dc002f8. Part of this (not merged!) pull request: https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/542.

Answer (score 3):

You could locate your webhook at a hard-to-guess URL.  Say:

```
https://my-host.com/webhooks/E36006BE2C4BABDEEF307C77E34F415B/my-hook
```

(That's 128-bits of random data - increase to whatever size feels comfortable).  Assuming you can trust github to keep this url secure, it's pretty likely that a client hitting that url can be trusted.

If the url should ever be compromised, it's a simple matter to just generate a new random URL and update your webserver.

Just make sure you're using a good source of entropy...

Comment: Yeah but then if you have a lot of web hooks you'd have to update them all with the new URL if your URL ever became compromised.

Comment: Isn't the URL clear-text once it is used and sent over the internet?

Comment: The request path is encrypted when sent via HTTPS.

Comment: It's funny that this got much less upvotes than the HTTP auth answer even though they are practically the same thing.