# How to prevent unwanted hook requests?

Tags: git, node.js, github

I developed an application that works with Github and Github Hooks, when a new hook request received, I just `update`/`clone` the repository (and then I do a little process on repository)

Because I accept all hook requests blindly, everyone can generate a hook request and send it t me.

I want to know how can I protect my application from unwanted hook requests?

Comment: Is that an open source application?

Comment: @Chronial Yes, that's an open-source one.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as it is not sure, how a hook request classifies as "unwanted"... @AfshinMehrabani: Please elaborate on this point.

Comment: @furtelwart I just changed the title, is it better now?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani: Unfortunately no. What do you define as "unwanted"? How do you decide, that a hook request is unwanted or wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Github does not include any secret information with the payload (based on https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks).

So your best defense is to make the url of your webhook hard to guess by using a random string in the url of your web hook.

You may also consider, although this may break over time, checking that `request.connection.remoteAddress` is within a range of addresses that are know to belong to Github host (Rackspace at the moment?).  This answer includes know ip addresses: [How to verify a post-receive hook request actually came from github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007030/how-to-verify-a-post-receive-hook-request-actually-came-from-github)