# github service hook and basic authentication

Tags: github, webhooks, git-post-receive

I'm trying to figure out how to secure a webhook reciever for a github service hook.

In the github manual pages, when you look in the section on what IP addresses github hooks will come from, it has this warning:

> "We highly recommend that you don't white list IPs for Service Hooks. Instead, setup HTTPS and basic authentication to verify incoming requests."

- https://help.github.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-does-github-use-that-i-should-whitelist#service-hook-ip-addresses

In the documentation on [post receive hooks](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) I don't see any way to set up basic authentication.

How can I use basic authentication with github post-recieve/service/web hook that notifies me of a commit to a repository?

Comment: superset question: how to do authenticated webhooks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007030/how-to-verify-a-post-receive-hook-request-actually-came-from-github

Comment: I saw that too; but the accepted answer is exactly what the quote above from github says NOT to do.  All the answers on that page seem sort of hokey, except for http://stackoverflow.com/a/20856954/1763984 which didn't used to be there (and I just upvoted it)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you can just use

```
https://yourUser:yourSecret@yoursite.net/path
```

like in any basic auth situation.

I will give it a try tomorrow, too :)
[https://github.com/blog/237-basic-auth-post-receives](http://github.com/blog/237-basic-auth-post-receives)

Comment: I just tried it right now: Go to your Repository->Settings->Service Hooks and use the syntax above in your WebhookUrl :)