# How to run post-receive hook on GitHub

Tags: git, github, githooks

how to run a post-receive hook in GitHub?. I know that there is the web-one but I want to write a custom script and do not want to receive a post from github.

Comment: Well you can't run your own code on the Github servers. That is why Github provides the option to receive notifications by HTTP POST.

Comment: I suppose if it did Circle CI and such wouldn't exist?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [post-receive hook of Github](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) are actually only **"WebHooks"**, to communicate with a web server whenever the repository is pushed to.

For security reason, you cannot run anything on the GitHub server side.

---

> When a push is made to your repository, we'll POST to your URL with a payload of JSON-encoded data about the push and the commits it contained.

You can use **[Requestbin](http://requestb.in/)** to [test your webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-webhooks).
(check that the [JSON actually comes from GitHub though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382587/6309))

---

Note: since late 2018, you *can* run actions on GitHub server-side, with **[GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)**.

> Actions are triggered by GitHub platform events directly in a repo and run on-demand workflows as autoscaled containers in response.
> With GitHub Actions you can automate your workflow from idea to production.

See examples with [`sdras/awesome-actions`](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions).

Other examples, provided by [Encryptex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10118045/encryptex) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041220/how-to-run-post-receive-hook-on-github/19043688?noredirect=1#comment133421796_19043688):

"**[How to setup continuous deployment of a website on a VPS using GitHub Actions](https://dev.to/knowbee/how-to-setup-continuous-deployment-of-a-website-on-a-vps-using-github-actions-54im)**" from [Igwaneza Bruce](https://github.com/knowbee).

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://dev.to/knowbee/how-to-setup-continuous-deployment-of-a-website-on-a-vps-using-github-actions-54im

Comment: @EncryptEx Good example indeed. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.