# Jenkins build is not triggered with git post-receive hook

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on windows machine, configured a project with git repo. My goal is to automatically build project when someone commits into github. To achieve this goal, i updated "Post-Receive" (no extn) file under .git/hooks directory.
Code looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://localhost:9090/job/MyProject/build?token=mytoken
```

When i execute `curl http://localhost:9090/job/MyProject/build?token=mytoken` command or `sh post-receive`, jenkins job will trigger.

Jenkins job is not triggered when i push changes into git repo (from another machine). Kindly share your thoughts which will help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, [GitHub supports Webhooks, not post-receive hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041220/how-to-run-post-receive-hook-on-github).

You can configure webhooks in the your GitHub repository settings: github.com/[owner]/[repository]/settings/hooks

However, if you're trying to fire off a Jenkins job, you should look into the existing Services hooks to Jenkins.

[image]