# How can I automatically synchronize a Github repository to a SourceForge repository

Tags: git, github, githooks, sourceforge

I have a git repository at SourceForge and now I need to move the repository from SourceForge to Github. I did it using Github import option given in following link.

https://import.github.com/new

[image]

Going forward I'm going to use the Github repository as the main repository where changes will push but I don't want to discontinue my SourceForge repository. Even though I will not push to SourceForge repository I want to setup an automated mechanism to synchronize changes for each push from Github to SourceForge. I found a Git option which can achieve this called “post-update” hooks and it works without any issue for repositories hosted in my internal servers.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

But Github seems not supporting for post-update hooks for security reasons and instead of that it supports for “Webhooks”

[How to run post-receive hook on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041220/how-to-run-post-receive-hook-on-github)

But if I use Webhooks, I may have to setup an intermediate server which listen for these Webhook notifications and push the changes to SourceForge.

**Question:**

**Is there any other setup I can follow to achieve directly synchronize a Github repository to a SourceForge repository without maintaining an intermediate repository as I explained with Webhooks?**

**Note:** Setting up Github repo and the SourceForge repo both as remotes in the developers local repository won't work in my case because there will be dozens of developers involve in contributing to the project and we don't have control over it.

Comment: hi there, use the github webhooks

Comment: @jsexpert If I use Github webhooks I need to use an intermediate server to listen to webhook notifications and then push change to sourceforge. I don't want to use a 3rd party server and I want to syncronize it directly from Github to sourceforge.

Comment: You may want to think about make some script in Travis-CI for automatic deployment.

Comment: It is 2023 and I came across this exact question myself. It seems the only way to sync a github repo with a SourceForge upstream is to add a remote reference in the git configuration while pushing to github:
https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/GitHub%20Importer/#source-code