# How do I push all branches to one remote, and only individual branches to others?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-remote

I have two remotes, `public` and `private`, and two branches, `master` and `learn`.

When I'm on `master` I'd like `git push` to push to both `public` and `private`; and when I'm on `learn` I'd like `git push` to push to just `private`.

I've tried `git push --all private -u`, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

---

In detail, I've done:

```
$ git remote remove public
$ git remote remove private
$ git remote add public https://github.com/.../A.git
$ git remote add private https://github.com/.../B.git
$ git push -u public master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from public.
$ git push --all private -u
Branch learn set up to track remote branch learn from private.
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from private.
```

Running `git branch -avv` (after manually pushing everything to each branch) gives:

```
* learn                  6489f4c [private/learn] ...
  master                 6489f4c [private/master] ...
  remotes/private/learn  6489f4c ...
  remotes/private/master 6489f4c ...
  remotes/public/master  6489f4c ...
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to specify multiple remotes for a single push

Comment: However, you could chain them with a post-receive hook on your public remote that would automatically push master to your private remote. This way you only push master to public, but it's then replicated to private.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII: That might work (especially if it's the only way!). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII: Also, FWIW, I mostly work within [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com), so if there's a solution that works there, I'd like that.

Comment: Because you're using Github, [you can't run git hooks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19041220/4233593), just their API for webhooks. So the simplest thing would probably be to just create an alias for two pushes.

Comment: Put the hook @JeffPuckettII suggests into an embedded shared-objects proxy repo, `git init --bare -s . .git/x-raxa-stuff/pushproxy`, that'll use almost no space, and set branch.master.push.  You could even do it in the pre-receive, the objects are available because they're shared.

Answer (score 0):

First add your remote repos info into git

```
     git remote add origin https://github.com/gitachyut/a.git
     git remote add nonorigin https://github.com/gitachyut/b.git
```

here origin, nonorigin is the name of the repo alias name

At the time of push, define the repo name just like below

```
    git push origin master

    git push nonorigin testing
```

Syntax

```
    git push {repo alias name } { branch name }
```

Comment: Can you explain how this relates to the question?