# Can the post-receive git hook be used to send email notification if a particular file changes

Tags: git, webhooks, post-receive-email

I am new to configuring git hooks and understand that post-receive can be used to send notifications after a successful push request. I would like to know how I could use it to send an email notification whenever a PR has a commit that changes a specific config file. Or maybe send the notification when the config file has been updated successfully?
A PR notification generally sends a list of all files that have been modified, but how can we highlight/ notify changes regarding a specific file alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A post-receive hook *that you write* can do anything *that you write it to do*.  There are example ones that send email, and you could presumably start with one of those and modify it to achieve your desired result, except for one huge stumbling block:

> I would like to know how I could use it to send an email notification whenever a PR has a commit that changes a specific config file.

Git does not have pull requests (in the GitHub sense, that is).  There is a Git command, `git request-pull`, that generates email messages someone can send, but that's all it does.  It won't invoke any post-receive hook.

> Or maybe send the notification when the config file has been updated successfully?

This, you can do, *provided you can set up a post-receive hook:*

> A PR notification generally sends a list of all files that have been modified, but how can we highlight/ notify changes regarding a specific file alone?

A Pull Request notification *from GitHub* is generated *by GitHub*.  They do not run arbitrary post-receive hooks.  You can write *actions;* whether you can generate email in an action, and if so, how, I do not know, but see [How to run post-receive hook on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19041220/1256452) to get started with this.

GitHub Actions are specific to GitHub: they are not available from other Git hosting sites.  (Other sites generally have something very similar, but not the same.)  Use the [github-actions](/questions/tagged/github-actions) tag for questions about GitHub Actions.

Comment: You're absolutely correct - great answer.  Thank you, too, for emphasizing that "git <> GitHub".  GitHub features like "pull requests" are *NOT* necessarily part of "git" per se.  A distinction that's often lost on a lot of people.